# Archiving millions of 5KB records

Tags: mysql, database, storage, archive

I have an application that relies on a mysql database that needs to archive raw records after they're processed.

Each records is around 5KB of text in one field and 3 or 4 other fields.

Around 100'000 records a week will need to be archived. The records will never be edited and very rarely accessed.

Currently they are being added to an `ARCHIVE` engine table in mysql, but the engine's limitations (editing, purging, deleting etc) are overweighing the space benefit, changing to an uncompressed engine will take up too much space..

So we're looking for an efficient way to store those records that is a bit more flexible than an `ARCHIVE` table.

Any suggestions for the best way to do it?

The app runs on AMAZON AWS, so we can make use of these ressources..

Comment: InnoDB has compression, too: [Enabling Compression for a Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-compression-usage.html)

Comment: @ypercube Yeah, we tried using a compressed raw format but it didn't help much..